# Add class to groupHeader in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have written following to group headers in jqgrid.

```
$("#datagrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
              useColSpanStyle: true, 
              groupHeaders:[{startColumnName: 'abc', numberOfColumns: 11, titleText: 'Group'}]
            });
```

I have following css class

```
.mClass{
font-color:red;
text-align: center;
//more styles
}
```

I would like to know how should I add this class to group header cell(that is the cell containing the title 'Group'?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) you can use className property to add a certain class. More you can find in [Guriddo documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#set-group-headers)

Here the code example:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle:true,
    groupHeaders : [
       { "startColumnName":'OrderID', "numberOfColumns":2, "titleText":'Order Info', "className" : "myclass1 myclass2" },
       { "startColumnName":'ShipName', "numberOfColumns":3, "titleText":'Shipping Details' }
    ]
});
```